# Moment.js local relative time

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have dates in my database set to Europe/London time. I am using Moment.js to show relative time e.g. "3 minutes ago". This works fine for me as I am in the same timezone, but for example, someone who is PST timezone would see "in 8 hours". How can I fix this?

My current code is like this:

`$('time').text( moment( '2016-01-22 18:00:00' ).fromNow() );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To echo Jon's answer, moment's relative time functionality is strictly UTC based, so the behavior you describe won't actually happen, unless you are interpreting the original timestamp in local time.

It's hard to say if you're doing that or not, as you didn't give a sample value of the input string.

If your times are indeed UTC based, but that's not reflected in the input string, then use `moment.utc` instead of just `moment`.

And no, London is not the same as UTC.

Comment: My app is storing dates like '2016-01-22 18:00:00'. Luckily I can change the app to use UTC time instead of GMT without having to change the database records.

Comment: I am doing this now: `var localTime = moment.utc('2016-01-22 18:00:00').toDate();` and then `moment(localTime).fromNow();`

Comment: That will work, but you can just use `fromNow` where you currently have `toDate`.  No need for the interim step.

Comment: Sweet :) I based it off this - https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/4/. Will change it, thanks Matt!

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the best approach is to store the date in UTC and then convert this to the local time zone for display.  Note that this is not necessarily the same as London time because UTC does away with daylight savings time nonsense.  You can do everything that you need with the date class provided the time stamp stored in the database does not have to deal with the vagaries of time zone and DST.  The date class maintains its own epoch internally as milliseconds elapsed since midnight 1 January 1970 UTC.  You can evaluate the difference between two Date objects as follows:

```
var agora = Date.now();
var stored = ... // the date that was stored in your database
var diff_msec = agora.getTime() - stored.getTime();
```

Knowing that the difference and that its units are milliseconds, you can convert the difference to whatever units are best for presentation.

Comment: London is GMT. Do you mean output it on the back-end in the user's timezone?

Comment: London is only GMT in the winter.  In the summer, it's BST (GMT+1).