# Moment.js local time zone issue

Tags: javascript, momentjs

Using the code below, I am getting a Date from my database (SQL) and displaying it in a datapicker form field. The date displays fine for me but if I change my time zone (EST) in my system to one that is behind mine, the field will display the date as the day before. Does anyone know why this is occurring and how to fix it?

```
var NetNewBusinessDate = moment(model.NetNewBusinessDate).format("M/D/YYYY"));

model.NetNewBusinessDate == "/Date(1494561600000)/"
```

Comment: You would need to show more than that line of code. Like the two different date strings returned by `model.NetNewBusinessDate` depending on the time zone setting.

Comment: Good call. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer here. [Moment.js local relative time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34951990/moment-js-local-relative-time)

The issue had to do with UTC conversion and Moment.js has an extension method that handles that. I just used `moment.utc` instead of `moment` and it worked like a charm!